# Java initiating instances with an ArrayList

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java and I'm trying to write a maze generator based on the DFS algorithm, however, I have a problem with initiating.

Here's the code:

```
class MazeCell {
    int x, y;
    boolean visited, onStack;
}

class MazeGenerator {
    Stack stack = new Stack();
    Random myRand = new Random();
    int columns = 80;
    int rows = 25;

    public void Generate() {
        ArrayList <MazeCell> cells = new ArrayList <MazeCell> (columns*rows);
        int x, i = 0, y = 0;
        for (y = 0; y < rows; ++y) {
            for (x = 0; x < columns; ++x) {
                cells.set(i) = new MazeCell;
                cells.set(i).visited  = false;
                cells.set(i).onStack = false;
                cells.set(i).x = x;
                cells.set(i).y = y;
                ++i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone help and tell me what would be the best way to do it? Am I trying it in the right way?

Comment: Can you clarify "I have a problem with initiating"? How exactly it [*doesn't work*](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) for you?

Comment: I don't know what to use as an element in the set(int index, E element) function that it requires

Comment: Can you explain why you even use `set` here? The proper method for your situation is `add`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Generate()` function, you have initialized the `cells` ArrayList. So, after initialization, it is an empty ArrayList. Please note,

> [ArrayList.set(int index, E element)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_set.htm) replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element.

So, setting an element in an empty ArrayList doesn't make sense. You probably need,

> [ArrayList.add(E e)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_add.htm) method which appends the specified element `E` to the end of the list.

Also, having for loop condition like, `for(y = 0; y > rows; ++y)` and `for(x = 0; x > columns; ++x)` doesn't make sense. You should follow the suggestion given by @shmosel in his answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, makes sense now

Answer (score 2):

There are a quite a few logical and syntactical errors in your code. Try this instead, and compare them to see the mistakes:

```
for (int y = 0; y < rows; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < columns; ++x) {
        MazeCell cell = new MazeCell();
        cell.visited = false;
        cell.onStack = false;
        cell.x = x;
        cell.y = y;
        cells.add(cell);
    }
}
```